# Invert "checked" value of a mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material2, angular-material-7

When a Angular Material `mat-checkbox` (https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) is checked it has the value "true". When it is unchecked it has the value "false".

Is there a way to turn this behaviour around? I need just the opposite. A checked checkbox should serialize to "false" and a unchecked one should serialize to "true" when calling `this.filterFormGroup.getRawValue()`.

I was hoping that there is something like this:

```html
<mat-checkbox [myCustomCheckedValue]="false" [myCustomUnCheckedValue]="true"></mat-checkbox>
```

Or do I need to create a custom directive like so:

```html
<mat-inverted-checkbox></mat-inverted-checkbox>
```

My goal is that this code:

```ts
    this.filterGroup = new FormGroup({
        resolved: new FormControl(),
    });

    this.filterGroup.getRawValue();
```

returns `{resolved: false}` when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tobias, a formControl exists even if you don't have an input. So, if you have

```ts
  form = new FormGroup({
    resolved: new FormControl()
  })
```

you can use something like:

```html
<mat-checkbox [checked]="!form.value.resolved"
              (change)="form.get('resolved').setValue(!$event.checked)">
   Check me!
</mat-checkbox>
```

see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emxwx7?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html)

Note, if you only have a unique formControl then:

```ts
mycontrol=new FormControl()
```

you use

```html
<mat-checkbox [checked]="!mycontrol.value"
              (change)="mycontrol.setValue(!$event.checked)">
   Check me!
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: You don't need to bind `[checked]` (unless you want the initial state checked), but you should set the initial true/unchecked value on the `FormControl`.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wants to do this without a FormControl, the simplest solution is to bind the `value` input to the `checked` property:

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox [value]="!checkbox.checked">
  {{ checkbox.value }}
</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/8558186/eliseo and made it "false" or "null" for the API:

```html
<mat-checkbox (change)="resolvedFormControl.setValue($event.checked ? false.toString() : null)"
    [checked]="resolvedFormControl.value === false.toString()">
            Resolved
</mat-checkbox>
```

and in the component:

```ts
this.resolvedFormControl = new FormControl(null);
this.resolvedFormControl.setValue(false.toString());

this.filterGroup = new FormGroup({
    resolved: this.resolvedFormControl,
});

this.filterGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.filterGroup.getRawValue());
    // resolved is either 'false' or null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom Pipe to change the received values to the way you want it to be.
Like if the received value is true, It will convert the value in the desired way that is false in your case.

Comment: I am not sure where you think the pipe could be inserted. Can you add a snippet of your solution?

Comment: I have used a variable test which is initialized with true and i use the invert pipe to transform the value to false

Comment: let me know in case that helps @tobias47n9e

Comment: @VaibhavKaushik, it's better you write the code in the answer and not put a link in stackblitz (or put the link in the answer). This stackblitz can "disappear" or change and the answer left incomplete