# Angular Material datepicker to set timestamp as form control value

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
                <input
                  [value]="question.timestampToMoment(row.controls[column.name].value)"
                  [formControlName]="column.name"
                  [required]="column.required"
                  matInput
                  [matDatepicker]="picker"
                  (dateChange)="question.onDateChange($event)"
                  placeholder="Choose a date"
                />
```

I would like the `FormControl` that's attached to this `datepicker` have the timestamp as the value, so that the timestamp can be sent back to the backend. Then in setting the value of this `datepicker` when the value comes back from the backend, I would need to convert it back to a `moment` object from the timestamp.

I imagine `timestampToMoment` would look like: `return moment(value * 1000)`

I can't figure out how to implement `onDateChange` or any other way to make this work though. The `datepicker` uses `moment.js`.

Comment: the most easy is not include the formControl in the mat-Date-picker and use (dateChange) to change the formControl and [value] to show a date . Remember, a FormControl exist indepent of there are a input or not. It's some loks like anohter question, but with a check-box, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185576/invert-checked-value-of-a-mat-checkbox/57189478#57189478

Comment: Ah, thanks. This completely works. I was focused on the idea that the FormControl and the datepicker were one entity. If you add this as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Eliseo, the trick here is to not include the `FormControl` in the `datepicker` input, and use the `dateChange` event to manually change the value of the `FormControl`. The `value` for the `datepicker` can in turn be set by passing the timestamp into a function.

```
<input
  [value]="timestampToMoment(form.controls[key].value)"
  [required]="required"
  matInput
  [matDatepicker]="picker"
  (dateChange)="onDateChange($event, form.controls[key])"
  placeholder="Choose a date"
/>

timestampToMoment(value: number): Moment {
  return moment(value * 1000);
}

onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<any>, control: AbstractControl): void {
  control.setValue(event.value.valueOf() / 1000);
}
```